# XPS 13 - one TB port faster than the other?

Tags: hdmi, dell-xps, thunderbolt, refresh-rate

I have a new XPS 13 9300 with 2x TB3 ports. I use a Dell WD19TB dock to connect to my monitor, an LG 34GK950F. The monitor handles up to 144hz which I make use of through my gaming PC.
When connecting the XPS up to the monitor I get the option for 60hz, 85hz and 100hz refresh rate which is great, 100hz works well and feels smooth on desktop use.

I just reorganized my desk and found that using the other TB3 port I can only get 60hz and the higher rates are not available.
I have also noticed that when closing the lid of my laptop the external monitor only stays on when plugged in to the TB port that I can get a higher refresh from, I have checked windows settings for what happens when the lid is closed.

Does anyone know if there is a reason for this? It's minor I know but I'm curious as I assumed the two ports would be identical.

Cheers

Comment: Have you consulted the XPS' manual and Dell's support site?